# How to only allow a float (money value) input?

Tags: python-3.x

How can i get only a money value input with out splitting dollars and cents?

I tried .isdigit() but then i can only use int not floats.

```py
def deposit():
    deposit_amount = 0
    print('How much would you like to deposit?')
    print('No decimal')
    deposit_dollars = input('Dollar amount: ')   
    if deposit_dollars.isdigit():
        print('Double digit ex: 02 = 2 cents')
        deposit_cents =input('Cents: ') 
        if deposit_cents.isdigit():
            if int(deposit_cents) <= int(99):
                f = open(login+'.txt','a')
                i = datetime.now() 
                f.write(deposit_dollars+'.'+deposit_cents+','+i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')+','+'Deposit'+'\n')
                f.close() 
                display_menu()
```

this code works but I'd like to have the input be in one entry. ex: 23.45.
while not allowing a random letter or symbol other that decimal point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: TL;DR of duplicate: `amount = float(input('How much would you like to deposit? '))`

Comment: right, but how do i address the error when a string is entered?

Comment: Well, your current code fails silently, which is worse than an error. But for handling exceptions, use a [`try`-`except` block](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: FYI, it usually not a good idea to use `float` to store money. You may experience rounding errors. It's best to store the money in the lowest denomination as an integer. In the US that would be cents.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks for the advice ill change that

Comment: @wjandrea Your last comment with the try: except: worked. I'm still very new and learning.